# Cumulative/Running Total in Yii2 gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am trying to achieve running total in yii2 grid view. I have tried below but I can't quite get the expected result. The data is from an active dataprovider.

```
$runningtotal = 0;

echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'pjax' => true,
'columns' => [

    [
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
        'attribute' => 'pax',
        'format' => 'decimal',
        'pageSummary' => true
    ],
    [
        'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use($runningtotal){
            $runningtotal+= ($model->pax);
            return $runningtotal;
        },
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
        'label' => 'Running Total',
        'attribute' => 'paxtotal', //'format' => 'decimal',
    ],
],
]);
```

My challenge is having the running total on this gridview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is that `use` passes in variables by value and not reference.

To pass in a variable by reference use `&`:

```
'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use (&$runningtotal) {
```

Comment: It Worked for me. Thank you so much. Was looking for this only

Comment: Next page it's resetting any solution for that